# WPF ListView CellTemplate Checkbox size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set a `ListView` with a checkbox in one of its columns using the following XAML code:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Width="1400" ItemsSource="{Binding CVS.View}" FontSize="40" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Show">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Width="500" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="700" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Setting the `Width` property of the CheckBox doesn't do anything.

This is when the width is set to 500:

[image: Width=500]

And this is when it is set to 50:

[image]

You can see that the width has changed since the names are much closer, but the size of the checkbox remained the same.

I tried also changing the `GridViewColumn` width and same results

Comment: What do you expect? The square won't get bigger. What is your qquestion?

Comment: I noticed that. My question is why and how to make it bigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the checkbox style itself, go for something like this:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
    </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
</CheckBox>
```